# Uploading and Downloading files using GWT

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, download

Is there a way to upload and download files to a svn server using GWT? I have had no luck so far and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: which IDE you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in the server side whit some 3'rd party library's like SVNKit 
then you can get some information (Transfer over the wire whit something like RPC) and show in GWT client side